# How can I install Tarantula on Windows?

Tags: testing, system, tarantula

Is there any way to install Tarantula on windows?
Is this a good tool for a QA team, for keeping track of test plans and stories.(Any other open source QA management systems for teams)

Comment: Did you try TestLink?

Answer (score 0):

you can try trello for maintaining stories. link : https://trello.com/

Answer (score 0):

Tarantula is a good tool for Manual Testing!

Yet one needs to think about interfacing with automation testing...

For this, we recommend using TestLink [this is the latest version](https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/tree/testlink_1_9/).

About your question about how to install on windows: the Tarantula is just the code for running on your server...

Hoop this helped you!